# Can Promise.all take in an array of all non-promise elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, promise

Promise.all resolves when all the promises in its array resolves, but there is an example where an element of the input array is not a promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Using_Promise.all

so i'm wondering, can Promise.all take in an array of all non-promise elements?

Comment: yes it can, but why would you need such a thing?

Comment: @JaromandaX If you have an array where things could or could not be promises, this will avoid having to check each thing

Comment: yes, I Know that @JuanMendes - I think I read the question wrong :p

Answer (score 4):

`Promise.all` calls [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) on all of the argument elements before doing anything with them. For those that already are promises, nothing happens; for thenables, they'll be converted to a proper promise, and everything else will get wrapped in a fulfilled promise.