# Does an await-ed function inside an async function have to return a promise? (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
async function someAsyncFunc() {
    const [user, categories] = await Promise.all([
        asyncGetUser(),
        asyncGetCategories()
    ]);
    const mapping = await asyncMapUserWithCategory(user, categories);
};
```

To get the `mapping`, I need to get `user` and `categories` first. These come from a DB, so I use `Promise.all` to fetch them at once and then feed them to `asyncMapUserWithCategory()` (not sure why I had put await before that, but nevermind). I am pretty sure `asyncGetUser()` and `asyncGetCategories()` must return promises. EDIT: *.., or a value. (sorry, forgot about this)*

In case I did the same without `Promise.all` (below, I suppose slower) would the await-ed function also need to return promises for this to work?

```
async function someAsyncFunc() {
    const user = await asyncGetUser();
    const categories = await asyncGetCategories();
    const mapping = await asyncMapUserWithCategory(user, categories);
};
```

Comment: async function get automatically wrapped in promises if they don't return a promise Try the following: `await (async function() {return 1})(); (async function() {return 1})().then(x => console.log(x))`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer:

No.

---

### Why?

You can return a **normal value** OR **a Promise**. If it's a **normal value** it is converted into a `resolved Promise` before being assigned to the variable. I would surmise the intention of this in the specification was that it would be useful for control structure flexibility, but the truth is if you're not `awaiting` a Promise outright, you will find that almost all of the time you may as well be using a normal variable and you're just spinning gears:

---

### What does MDN Say?

[image: Description of Await]
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Description)

### Exceptions:

Most of the time, as stated, `await` is only useful when utilized with a `Promise`. To be balanced, an example of a situation where a value could be useful to use with an `await` function is when providing either an API call or a reference to test data depending on the current Environment.

Otherwise it's a rarity for reasons already stated. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Awaiting something that isn't a promise won't be a syntax error or anything like that. However, it also won't do anything of note. You havn't told it what to wait for, and so it will resume immediately.

My recommendation: If the code is synchronous, leave off the await to make it more obvious that it's synchronous. If it's asynchronous, then return a promise and await that promise.

Answer (score 0):

> I am pretty sure `asyncGetUser()` and `asyncGetCategories()` must return promises.

[No, they don't need to.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42051213/1048572)

> Would the `await`-ed function also need to return promises for this to work?

No, [it's the same for `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49086056/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

You can await a non-async (non Promise returning) function:

```
function sum(num1, num2) { return num1 + num2 };
async function main() {
    const s = await sum(2, 3); // this resolves immediately
}
```

---

Yep, your second function runs slower:

```
async function someAsyncFunc() {
    const user = await asyncGetUser();
    const categories = await asyncGetCategories(); 
    const mapping = await asyncMapUserWithCategory(user, categories);
};
```

because `asyncGetCategories()` will only be called after `asyncGetUser()` has settled.

---

Whereas in your first example, these two calls run simultaneously:

```
async function someAsyncFunc() {
    const [user, categories] = await Promise.all(asyncGetUser(), asyncGetCategories()];
    const mapping = await asyncMapUserWithCategory(user, categories);
};
```

This would run similarly to:

```
async function someAsyncFunc() {
    const userPromise = asyncGetUser();
    const categoriesPromise = asyncGetCategories();
    const user = await userPromise;
    const categories = await categoriesPromise;
    const mapping = await asyncMapUserWithCategory(user, categories);
};
```

In both these examples, the two async operations are started simultaneously, without one waiting on the other to settle.

Answer (score 0):

First, respect to the title of your question, **all functions marked with `async` returns a Promise**, even if you don't return **explicitly** one.

> In case I did the same without Promise.all (below, I suppose slower) would the await-ed function also need to return promises for this to work?

Yes (logically, to work, don't). If you use `await`, it means that the function *await-ed* returns a Promise; otherwise, there is not logic reason to use await in synchronous functions.

> I suppose slower

Well, there is no major difference using `Promise.all` than running the promises each per time. In fact, `Promise.all` does not **execute** the promise because the **task** of the promise is started when you instantiate it.